# Remote debugging throws strange exception

Tags: c#, uwp, remote-debugging

When remote debugging my UWP application, VS always throws the following error after deployment process starts:

> > Error: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Remote machine is a Win10 VM. The application runs fine when I select "Local Machine" from target machines list.

Things that I have ensured:

1. VM and development machine can see each other.
2. Remote tools are installed on the VM and Remote debugger is running.
3. Remote debugger says "[UserX] connected" when I start deployment, so VS is talking to it.
4. I have tried all 3 modes of authentication (None, Windows, Universal) and neither works.
5. I have restored NuGet packages, rebuilt all projects in the solution etc.
6. I have tried "Debug instead of Launch" checkbox and "Uninstall and reinstall my package" options too.

Has anyone else seen this behavior?

(*Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation* generally contains a more specific exception inside it that shows what actually went wrong, but in this case I do not have any way to dig into the main exception).

Here's a snapshot of Output window:

[image]

### Edit

Some more information. The error changes to the following if I choose **Universal** authentication:

> > Error: Field not found: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ImmersiveProjectServices.BootstrapperOperationPackage.StandardCollectorCpuAgent'.

Comment: Sigh, pretty typical VS2015 lossage.  Do keep in mind that this has nothing to do with the remote debugger, it is the deployment that failed.  Not that debugging is going to work that well after this.  Try to get a better diagnostic by starting another instance of VS, use Debug > Attach to attach to devenv.exe and make it stop on all CLR exceptions.

Comment: @HansPassant: VS doesn't stop at the exception. Is `devenv.exe` the right process to attach?

Comment: @close-voter: Too broad??? There should be one answer to this question **at most** if I'm lucky.

Comment: If you create a blank uwp app, could it be deployed successfully? Also, it will be better to provide the vs version, the develop machine os version.

Comment: @Sunteen-MSFT: Haven't tried with blank app. I'll post it when I do. The OS is Win10 x64 on both the development and the remote machines. Additionally the remote machine also has got Anniversary Update. VS2015 Community Update 3 on both machines.

Comment: @Sunteen-MSFT: Right. I can generate this issue with blank UWP application as well. Exception thrown at deploy.

Comment: In that case ,did you have another remote machine which is not a virtual machine for testing? As you known, it shouldn't have issues on this feature itself, if  a blank uwp app can lead this issue , the reason must be the environments of the two machines. I will help you test it on my side as well.

Comment: @Sunteen-MSFT: Just to help you a bit more, I tried it on a real remote machine with Win10 (AU) and could still see the issue.

Comment: @dotNET, I tested it , I cannot reproduce your issue. Did you use the newest debugger tool? Please try to re-install the remote tool in [this page](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/).

Comment: @Sunteen-MSFT: I downloaded remote debugger update 3 from the link you provided and reinstalled it on the VM. Still facing the same exception. Attaching VS to another instance does not catch any exceptions either. Feeling dead in the water.